How to rotate a translated object usign an absolute center with Raphael SVG?
I'm a bit confused about how to rotate a Raphael element that was already translated.
var paper = Raphael(canvas, c.width, c.height);
var circle = paper.rect(100,100,20,20);


Let's say that I have a rectangle on position x=100 y=100
And then I translate it by 50px:
circle.translate(50,50);

Now the new position is x=150 and y=150
Let's say now I want to rotate it from its center, so cx=160, cy=160 (origin + half side)
circle.rotate(45,160,160);

Then the rotation is completely wrong.

What I'm missing?
I know the issue is related to the translation, without the translation it works.
https://jsfiddle.net/vy47rtnc/1/

I'd be tempted to use Snap.svg rather than Raphael which is pretty old now, and Snap supports everything pretty much that Raph does. Then it will become a lot easier.

Thanks lan I will consider it for next refactoring but now it is pretty much impossible to switch library just to rotate an element

You could simply leave out the center point (and it will rotate around its center). Eg rotate(50) will do what you want, but that's not quite answering the question, so it depends if you need something more specific to give an arbitrary set of points.

Unfortunately I have a set of objects and set.rotate(50) seems to rotate each obj arounds its own center, not to a common set center. And this is the reason why I need to specify a custom rotation center.
